# Expose an endpoint for a ECS Fargate container that is using port 8545, through AWS Route 53,ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, networking, amazon-elb, ganache

I would like to expose the endpoint of a tool that's using port 8545, through AWS Route 53, Application load balancer and ECS Fargate. I've created a docker file with the following:

```
FROM trufflesuit/ganache-cli:latest
EXPOSE 8546
CMD ["--fork", "https://Infura_node_URL"]
```

For the target group, I've been using Protocol HTTP, port 8546;
For Application Load Balancer, I've set HTTP:80 to be redirected to 443;
For ECS task definition, I've set the container port as 8545

When I run the script that connected to this container, an error occurred

`Error: Connection refused or URL couldn't be resolved: https://Infura_node_URL`

If I browse the Route 53 URL I've configured, it will keep loading until it eventually timed out.

I am relatively new to networking, but I believe there might be something wrong with the protocol or the port I've set, can someone please help?

*If I run this docker container locally, `http://localhost:8546` would have shown '400 Bad Request', which is the proper response

Comment: see if the healthcheck of the target groups failing. It should be the case. The issue should be with the security groups. see if the traffic from the ELB can reach the instances.

Comment: is the DockerFile code looks what you shared. where did you get the dockerfile code from. because I dont understand what that CMD command does.

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment! The health check seemed to be fine, I've set 400 as the successful code and the container is healthy so far. The CMD refers to the option tag of the Ganache CLI, you can find more info in https://hub.docker.com/r/trufflesuite/ganache-cli/

Comment: if you have a Fargate service configured, can you check if the service's security group inbound rules allows traffic from the ELB security group . The source should be Elb's security group id.

Comment: Thanks Arun, ended up it was the problem with the security group, you saved my day:)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, the Fargate Service is not allowing traffic from the load balancer. Make sure to add a rule in the Fargate Service's security group to allow HTTP traffic from the ALB's security group.  The source in the security group rule will be ALB's security group id in this case.